# Mapping set in dataframe column to another dataframe / dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a newbie question - what I want to do is concat 2 columns holding some names separated with comma, create set (to drop duplicates). Then I would have for each dataframe row a set of names and for each of these names I want to look up some dict / df called 'countries'.

```
countries = pd.DataFrame(
    [["LOW", ["A", "D"]],
     ["MEDIUM", ["B", "E"]],
     ["HIGH", ["C", "F"]],], columns=['Risk_level', 'Country_code'])

my_df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'B,A'],['B', 'C,C']], columns=['id_1', 'id_2'])
```

What I tried is:

```
my_df["country_codes"] = (my_df["id_2"] + "," + my_df["id_1"]).astype('str')
my_df["country_codes"] = my_df["country_codes"].str.split(",").apply(set)
my_df['country_risks'] = my_df['country_codes'].map(
    countries.explode('Country_code').set_index('Country_code')['Risk_level'])
```

What I want to get is to have for each row a list of risks, so:

```
my_df['country_risks'] = pd.Series([["LOW", "MEDIUM"], ["MEDIUM", "HIGH"]])

| id_1 | id_2 | country_risk   |
|------|------|----------------|
| A    | B,A  | Low, Medium    |
| B    | C,C  | Medium, High   |
```

I know its a mess but I tried to explain it as clear as I could. Im stuck in the middle with how to map each element in set to dict/dataframe for each row. I could iterate over df but Id rather not. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you please add a table of expected results?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
countries = pd.DataFrame(
    [["LOW", ["A", "D"]],
     ["MEDIUM", ["B", "E"]],
     ["HIGH", ["C", "F"]],], columns=['Risk_level', 'Country_code'])

my_df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'B,A'],['B', 'C,C']], columns=['id_1', 'id_2'])

my_df["country_codes"] = (my_df["id_2"] + "," + my_df["id_1"]).astype('str')

my_df["country_codes"] = my_df["country_codes"].str.split(",").apply(set)

dfe=my_df.explode('country_codes')
dfe['country_risk'] = dfe['country_codes'].map(countries.explode('Country_code').set_index('Country_code')['Risk_level'])

my_df['country_risk'] = dfe.groupby(level=0)['country_risk'].agg(list)

my_df
```

Output:

```
  id_1 id_2 country_codes    country_risk
0    A  B,A        {A, B}   [LOW, MEDIUM]
1    B  C,C        {B, C}  [MEDIUM, HIGH]
```

You can explode your my_df, map the codes, and groupby agg list then assign back to original dataframe.